# Pass param after click

Tags: kotlin, button, click

What I try to do is that when I open the fragment, the recyclerView shows me the current date and when I click on the button, it changes that date and shows me in the recylerView But I don't know how to do it.
As you say when opening the fragment it does not have url until the click is made

formatted is always today

```
    class MainProgMovis : AppCompatActivity() {

    var volleyRequest: RequestQueue? = null
    var recipeList: ArrayList<Recipe>? = null
    var recipeAdapter: RecipeListAdapter? = null
    var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    var MAIN_URL = ""

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.guia_list_volley)

        val current = LocalDateTime.now()

        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
        var formatted = current.format(formatter)
        val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, dd-MM-yyyy")
        val formatt = current.format(format)

        btn_button.setOnClickListener {

            var dt = formatted.toString()

            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
            val c = Calendar.getInstance()
            c.time = sdf.parse(dt)
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1) // number of days to add

            formatted = sdf.format(c.time) // dt is now the new date

            println("Current Date and Time is dt1: $formatted")

            MAIN_URL = "http://www.myurl/$formatted?v=json"

            getRecipe(MAIN_URL)
        }

        //MAIN_URL = "http://www.myurl/$formatted?v=json"

        tv_fech.text = formatt
        recipeList = ArrayList()

        volleyRequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        getRecipe(MAIN_URL)
    }

    fun getRecipe(url: String) {
        val id_code: String= intent.getStringExtra("id_code")
        val recipeRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url, Response.Listener {
                    response: JSONObject ->
                try {
                    val resultArray = response.getJSONObject("data")
                    val resultArray2 = resultArray.getJSONObject(id_code)
                    val resultArray3 = resultArray2.getJSONObject("DATOS_CADENA")

                    val resultArray4 = resultArray2.getJSONArray("PROGRAMAS")

                    tv_Text.text = resultArray3["NOMBRE"].toString()

                    println("xxx: " + resultArray4)

                    for (i in 0..resultArray.length() - 1) {
                        var recipeObj = resultArray4.getJSONObject(i)

                        var hora = recipeObj.getString("HORA_INICIO")
                        var programa = recipeObj.getString("TITULO")

                        var recipe = Recipe()
                        recipe.hora = hora
                        recipe.programa = programa

                        recipeList!!.add(recipe)

                        recipeAdapter = RecipeListAdapter(recipeList!!, this)
                        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

                        rv_guia_list.layoutManager = layoutManager
                        rv_guia_list.adapter = recipeAdapter

                    }

                    recipeAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }catch (e: JSONException) { e.printStackTrace()}
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                    error: VolleyError? ->
                try {
                    Log.d("Error:", error.toString())

                }catch (e: JSONException){e.printStackTrace()}
            })

        volleyRequest!!.add(recipeRequest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean formatted is always today after click the button ? I think var formatted has changed after you clicked on btn_button. But if what you mean is **formatted** on MAIN_URL, it won't change if you put the code outside of setOnClickListener. just place it at the bottom of setOnClickListener, and it will change.

```
tn_button.setOnClickListener {

        var dt = formatted.toString()

        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        c.time = sdf.parse(dt)
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1) // number of days to add

        formatted = sdf.format(c.time) // dt is now the new date

        println("Current Date and Time is dt1: $formatted")
        
        //this will update the formatted value after changed
        var MAIN_URL = "http://www.myurl/$formatted?v=json"

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   The solution:

 

btn_button.setOnClickListener {

        var dt = formatted.toString()

        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        c.time = sdf.parse(dt)
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1) // number of days to add

        formatted = sdf.format(c.time) // dt is now the new date

        println("Current Date and Time is dt1: $formatted")

        MAIN_URL = "http://www.myurl/$formatted?v=json"

        tv_fech.text = formatted
        recipeList = ArrayList()

        volleyRequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        getRecipe(MAIN_URL)
    }
```